# Azure DevOps API Create Project TF400734 (OnPrem)

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a suggested way to call [Projects - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) on a self hosted Azure DevOps Server?

If I use the API on OnPrem self hosted server, I get:

> TF400734: This service is only available with hosted Azure DevOps.

but my requirement, to create a new project over API, still exist.

---

#### What I try?

When I drag the network traffic on manual project creation I get a bunch of items that I can't handle:

[image]

Only the first event `projects` is a readable post request to:

```
https://myserverurl.com/MyCollection/_apis/projects
```

Payload:

```
id: "b87a57c9-6a50-415a-8da5-869499c02b0a"
status: 0
url: "https://myserverurl.com/MyCollection/_apis/operations/b87a57c9-6a50-415a-8da5-869499c02b0a"
```

There isn't any event that contains the passed project name and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the REST API **6.0** version is only supported on **Azure DevOps Services** (**VSTS**), not **Azure DevOps Server** (**TFS**).

And currently the highest REST API version that can be supported on **TFS** is **5.0**. Generally, the lower TFS version corresponds the lower API version. To view more details, you can see "[**API and TFS version mapping**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#api-and-tfs-version-mapping)".

So, for your case, if your TFS version is **2019** or **2020**, you can try the REST API **5.0** version. To create a project, you can try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! Do you know how I could configure the API version with the [npm azdev.WebApi](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api) package?

Comment: I follow the stack trace of the `azdev.WebApi` project api call and found out that this api use `application/json;api-version=5.0-preview.3` so it should work or? But I get the same error.

Comment: OK I switched to Postman and try the call, everything works instantly. So I think the `azdev.WebApi` make a simple thing to complex. Thanks for all!